# How can I round-trip format double precision values in Delphi?

Tags: xml, delphi, serialization

How can I round-trip format double precision values as a string in Delphi?

It's a feature I've seen in C#...the ability to format a double-precision number in a way that it will be de-serialized as exactly the same number.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#RFormatString .

I have been formatting them using the code below in Delphi but have found that the value is sometimes not identical:

```
  Result:=Format('%e', [d], FMyFormatSettings_FIXED_FORMAT);
```

I'm serializing using XML.  I've felt the need to format it myself instead of use IXMLNode's NodeValue method because my tests showed that NodeValue uses localization settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi's functions to convert between float and text are flawed in this regard. It is actually surprisingly difficult to do so accurately, and have functions that can round trip the floating point value.

As I see it you have two main possibilities to solve the problem:

- Use third party routines that don't have numerical inaccuracies. For instance `strtod` and `sprintf` from a C runtime library.
- instead of converting to human readable decimal, base 64 encode the 8 bytes of the double. Take care to deal with endianness.

Comment: Cave! `strtod` is not necessarily very good either. I've tested a few (including, but not only C++Builder's) and some have a difference of 2 ULP, while they should only be off by max. 1/2 ULP. I'm currently writing an exact TryStrToFloat() that is exact up to 1/2 ULP. That is not so easy without using (my) BigDecimals. With BigDecimals, it is **very**  simple (`D := Double(BigDecimal(str));`).

Comment: @Rudy Hardly surprising that the Embarcadero strtod is not good. But reputable ones are. And of course you need to use a high precision maths lib. Look at the ref code for dtoa on netlib.

Comment: Really good roundtrip code (which should use as few digits output as possible while still, when read back, resulting in exactly the same value) is not so easy at all.

Comment: @Rudy I know. Certainly too hard for Emba, although I don't think they have actually tried. They just used 80 bit Extended in the 32 compiler and hoped for the best. Even that's not good enough of course. There are plenty of decent strod versions around though, Emba's is presumably not one of them.

Comment: Not just Embarcadero's. Others as well (which surprised me a little). FWIW, `dtoa` is not the problem, and easily doable. Take a look at John Herbster's Delphi code (on CodeCentral), or mine (part of my DelphiBigNumbers). `strtod`or `atod`, i.e. from string to double is the problem. These often have differences of 1 ULP or more, not just in C, but also in other languages.

Comment: FWIW, John Herbster: http://codecentral.embarcadero.com/Item/19421; mine: https://github.com/rvelthuis/DelphiBigNumbers/blob/master/Source/Velthuis.ExactFloatStrings.pas

Comment: @RudyVelthuis -- thank you for your contribution as well; definitely some interesting options for me to consider -- I didn't know about them!

Comment: @David: have been reading about this a lot. There seems to be one de facto standard implementation that does correct rounding. Even gcc, VC++, etc. didn't do this always correctly. But these days, most implementations, even Java, have adopted that way: http://www.ampl.com/netlib/fp/dtoa.c (the strtod() in that source).

Comment: Just checked a few critical values found in some articles about errors, and VC++ is still not quite OK. But `D := Double(BigDecimal(S));` is correct in all these cases. <g>